# Wired internet not working on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet

I had installed Ubuntu 12.04 and then upgraded my machine to 14.04.
After the upgrade my wired internet has stopped working.

Here is the `ipconfig` output:

```
root@vyaw:/# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:e6:d7:5a:a5:db  
      inet6 addr: fe80::36e6:d7ff:fe5a:a5db/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:106158 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1772 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:7393113 (7.3 MB)  TX bytes:362147 (362.1 KB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f7c00000-f7c20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:7274 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7274 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:949502 (949.5 KB)  TX bytes:949502 (949.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:00:0b:96:e5:2e  
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:95306 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:95730 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:93910858 (93.9 MB)  TX bytes:17695478 (17.6 MB)
```

Here as we can see, IP address is not getting assigned.

Please help